# Vpn server ip configuration

Tags: vpn, openvpn, openwrt

I am trying to run openVpn server on my router to access it's lan network remotely. I got next error when I try to run it:

> daemon.err openvpn(myvpn)[7610]: Options error: --server directive
> network/netmask combination is invalid

Sadly but I not experienced in networking. I can't understand the exact place for vpn network interface in router, which ip/mask should I assign it. Below are my network interfaces and openvpn config (my router has public ip 46.xx.x33.118)

[image]

```
config openvpn 'myvpn'
option enabled '1'
option verb '3'
option port '1194'
option proto 'udp'
option dev 'tun'
option server '46.xx.x33.118 255.255.255.0'
option keepalive '10 120'
option ca '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
option cert '/etc/openvpn/my-server.crt'
option key '/etc/openvpn/my-server.key'
option dh '/etc/openvpn/dh.pem'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "server" directive in OpenVPN is used to allocate a range of (private) IP addresses that will be given out to OpenVPN clients.

From the [OpenVPN documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/):

"**--server network netmask ['nopool']**

*A helper directive designed to simplify the configuration of OpenVPN's server mode. This directive will set up an OpenVPN server which will allocate addresses to clients out of the given network/netmask. The server itself will take the ".1" address of the given network for use as the server-side endpoint of the local TUN/TAP interface.*"

This address block should therefore be in a private range. In your configuration it looks like you're using your public IP address (and a much wider subnet than you actually have available). That will not work and OpenVPN rightly complains. Look at some example OpenVPN configurations. Most OpenVPN configurations use a block of 10.x.x.x addresses for handing out to clients.